# mockito testing doFilter method, coverage 0%

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I have to make a junit mockito test on a java HttpFilter: i write some tests code on doFilter() but Code Coverage give me 0% of methods and line covered. Why?

doFilter return void and "req" is reassigned to a new isntance, so i guess the only  assert is in my FilterChain method where new req istance is passed if so happens.

How would you do the tests?
Thanks

Code to test:

```
public class XSSFilter implements Filter{

    public static final String XSS_FILTER_ACTIVE_PROPERTY_KEY = "XSSFilterActive";
    public static final String XSS_FILTER_ACTIVE_DEFAULT_VALUE = "false";
    private Logger logger;

    boolean isXssFilterActive= false;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        if (logger==null) {
            logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
        }
        isXssFilterActive = Boolean.parseBoolean(ResourceManagerListener.getProperty(XSS_FILTER_ACTIVE_PROPERTY_KEY, XSS_FILTER_ACTIVE_DEFAULT_VALUE));
        logger.info("isXssFilterActive ={}", isXssFilterActive);
        if (isXssFilterActive) {
            logger.info("filter XSS on");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {      
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        if (isXssFilterActive) {
            req = new XSSRequestWrapper(request);
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //empty
    }
    

}
```

The tests:

```
public class XssFilterTest {


    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest req;

    @Mock
    ServletResponse response;
    private AutoCloseable autoCloseableMock;



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        autoCloseableMock = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    //test XSS filtering ON: test request instance of XSSRequestWrapper 
    @Test
    public void testXSSFilterActiveTrue() throws Exception { 

        final MockedStatic<ResourceManagerListener> resourceManagerListenerMockedStatic = mockStatic(ResourceManagerListener.class);
        when(ResourceManagerListener.getProperty("XSSFilterActive", "false")).thenReturn("true");
        XSSFilter target = new XSSFilter();
        FilterConfig config = mock(FilterConfig.class);

        target.init(config);
        
        FilterChain filterChainConsumer =
                ( request, response) -> assertThat(request.getClass()).as("check filter is on").isEqualTo(XSSRequestWrapper.class);
        HttpServletRequest request = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req);
        target.doFilter(request,response, filterChainConsumer);
        resourceManagerListenerMockedStatic.close();
    }


    //XSS filtering off: test request instanceOf HttpServletRequestWrapper
    @Test
    public void testXSSFilterActiveFalse() throws Exception { //test quando spento

        final MockedStatic<ResourceManagerListener> resourceManagerListenerMockedStatic = mockStatic(ResourceManagerListener.class);
        //request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);// se non si usa l'injection con @Mock
        when(ResourceManagerListener.getProperty("XSSFilterActive", "false")).thenReturn("false");
        XSSFilter target = new XSSFilter();
        FilterConfig config = mock(FilterConfig.class);

        target.init(config);
        //deve essere wrappata come new XSSRequestWrapper
        FilterChain filterChainConsumer =
                ( request, response) -> assertThat(request.getClass()).as("check filter is off").isEqualTo(HttpServletRequestWrapper.class);
        HttpServletRequest request = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req);
        target.doFilter(request,response, filterChainConsumer);
        resourceManagerListenerMockedStatic.close();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        autoCloseableMock.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to coverage, but your test doesn't contain any assertions. In other words: it does not test anything

Comment: @knittl my test contai one assertion: assertThat(request.getClass()).as("check filter is on").isEqualTo(xxx.class), no?

Comment: Oh, there is indeed an assertion. But why is the assertion inside a filter chain? That looks fishy.

Comment: @knittl because look at the code inside..doFilter make this: req = new XSSRequestWrapper(request), but req is a mock object, and the only way that i  thinking is testing the type of instance... i cant do an assert on a mock! The mock dont change..Is it clever or naive? What you think can be done of different?